# Call/Assign a variable of a Class that implements an Interface

Tags: java, class, variables, inheritance, interface

I wrote an easy interface-inheritance example to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
interface Fruit{
     public void taste();    
}


class Banana implements Fruit {
     public String name = "Banana"; 
     public void taste(){
         System.out.println("yummy banana!");
     }


class Strawberry implements Fruit {
     public String name = "Strawberry"; 
     public void taste(){
         System.out.println("yummy strawberry!");
     }
}

class Lunch<Fruittype implements Fruit> {
     public Fruittype fruit;

     public void tasteit() {
         System.out.println("I'm going to eat a"+ fruit.name + "!" );
         // error: name cannot be resolved or is not a field
         fruit.taste();
     }
}

class exec {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Lunch<Banana> bananalunch  = new Lunch<>;
          bananalunch.fruit = new Banana();
          bananalunch.tasteit();
     }
}
```

So Banana and Strawberry are implementing Fruit. In the class Lunch I'm trying to call the fruit name and its function taste();
While calling the Function taste works just fine, i can't call the name (see: error in the comment)

Wanted Output:
I'm going to eat a Banana!
yummy banana!

Like I said, yummy banana works but the name can't be resolved. I tried to declare "public String name = "default""; in the Fruit interface. Then you can call it, but it will always say "default" and not the name in the actual class.

Is there a way to get a member of a generic Type that implements an interface?
P.S. I need to do it like this, of course this code was only for representation but I have a much larger more complicated code in which i encountered this problem- And I don't want to restructure it if not necessary.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would add a `getName()` method to the interface and implement standard getter/setter methods in the implementations of that interface.  (And make `name` private of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by trying to access an instance member directly - `fruit.name` - instead of via a method - `fruit.getName()`.

If you use a getter method, the correct method will be executed and return the required output.

That said, in this particular example it would make more sense to have a single `getName()` method in a base class, and a single `_name` variable in that base class, which is initialized to a different value based on the actual type of fruit class.

On the other hand, seeing that your `Fruit` is an interface rather than a base class, you can have each of the classes which implement that interface have a `getName()` method returning a different value.

For example:

```
class Strawberry implements Fruit {
     public String name = "Strawberry"; 
     public void taste(){
         System.out.println("yummy strawberry!");
     }
}
```

would become:

```
class Strawberry implements Fruit {
     public String getName () {
         return "Strawberry";
     }
     public void taste() {
         System.out.println("yummy strawberry!");
     }
}
```

You would have to add `getName()` to the interface:

```
interface Fruit {
     public String getName();
     public void taste();    
}
```

Finally, your `Lunch` class becomes:

```
class Lunch<Fruittype implements Fruit> {
     public Fruittype fruit;

     public void tasteit() {
         System.out.println("I'm going to eat a "+ fruit.getName() + "!" );
         fruit.taste();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't thought about that

Answer (score 0):

Case, when class implements interface, means that object of this class can do something that described in interface.

For example, every plane shape has area. So we can determine interface:

```
interface PlaneShape {
    int getArea();
}
```

Area of square is product of edges. And area of circle is product of 
squared radius by pi number divided by 2. So:

```
class Square implements PlaneShape {
    public int edge = 5;

    public int getArea() {
        return edge*edge;
    }   
}

class Circle implements PlaneShape {
    public int radius = 5;
    public int pi = 3.14;

    public int getArea() {
        return radius*radius*pi/2;
    }   
}
```

Interfaces use for abstraction. AreaCalculator operates with plane shapes, so it abstracts from any specific kind of plane shapes. AreaCalculator just knows that any shape can give him area  value by executing method getArea(). AreaCalculator don't know anything about special shape fields, like `edge` or `radius`.

```
class AreaCalculator<S implemets PlaneShape> {
    public S shape;

    public int calculateArea() {
        shape.getArea();
    }
}
```

By this way, in your example,`Lunch<Fruittype implements Fruit>` class don't know anything about fruits inner names, it doesn't "see" this fields, it only can invocate method `taste()`. You need to add method `getName()` to interface, and implement it.

On the subject of `name="default"` in interface. It declared in context of interface and hasn't any relation to implementations.